# SvelteKit keeping page data between pages

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

Is it possible to do the following:

Given a route such as `/foo/[slug]` with `+page.js` in it to load some data based on the slug, can the data be kept when navigating to `/foo/[slug]/bar` and available in the `+page.svelte`? The context of this is that there is some file being loaded to render on `/foo/[slug]` and that same file is used on `/foo/[slug]/bar`, so having the file preloaded is ideal. This approach would also require the file being loaded if `/foo/[slug]/bar` is visited first. I believe that load functions perform dependency checking. Reading through the docs, especially under the section about running the parent load function, it seems like this should be possible, but I can't quite figure it out.

Some approaches that would work are to use stores, or to use the layouts option, but is there a simpler approach?

I've tried getting the page data on the nested page directly, but it results in an empty object instead of the content from the `/foo/[slug]` page, which suggests that the data is not being loaded properly.

Comment: you should use a [+layout](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load#layout-data) at the slug level for all data that should be shared for pages below it

Comment: @pilchard so using `+layout.ts` at `/foo/[slug]` will have shared data in `/foo/slug/bar` ? The load function wont be run again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as @pilchard suggested, the solution was to use a `+layout.ts` in the `/foo/[slug]` route.

The final structure looked like this (on server as files are being read):

- `/foo/[slug]/+layout.server.js`
- `/foo/[slug]/+page.svelte`
- `/foo/[slug]/bar/+page.svelte`

In the layout file, I created the load function the read the file and output the data. In the `foo` page component, I use the data initially, then in the `bar` page component, you can just use `export let data` to get the data from the parent layout. This does not call the `load` function twice.